# Compiling Visual Studio extension - problem with Microsoft.VisualStudio namespace

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I'm learnig how create add-ons for VisualStudio.

First I downloaded this extension:
[Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 X++ Editor Extensions](https://www.doens.be/2017/08/microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-x-editor-extensions/)
(finally I needs a extension to the X ++ editor, hence the choice)

The extension works fine - I'm trying to edit it.

The project loads fine (I'm using Visual 2022), but when I try to compile it crashes into the Microsoft namespace.
For example:

- The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- The type or namespace name 'IAdornmentLayer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- The type or namespace name 'IWpfTextView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to solve the problem by adding the library `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` to the project, but then I got next errors.
For example - I have in project:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor;
```

This generate errors:

> The type or namespace name 'Text' does not exist in the namespace
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

For test I change `target framework` from `.NET framework 4` to `.NET framework 4.5` (and change node `SupportedFrameworkRuntimeEdition` in `\obj\Debug\extension.vsixmanifest` file) - in this configuration compiling is done correctly (but extension not works in X++ editor - so this not resolve my problem).

I'm using

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.3.4
- Windows Server 2012 R2

How can I solve this problem?

Regards,
Tomasz

Comment: We can see that [If you want to build this project to make changes yourself, it need to be built with Visual Studio 2010 SDK](https://github.com/jaestevan/AX2012-Editor-Extensions/wiki/Build-the-extensions-and-make-your-own-changes!). Maybe you can create an issue [here](https://github.com/jaestevan/AX2012-Editor-Extensions/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created Virtual Machine with Windows 7, installed Visual Studio Professional 2010 SP1 + SDK - on this setup everything works fine.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider adding an answer and changing its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)